# Rails 4: Update user status based on another model conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've Booking model which is has column:

```
:id
:user_id
:status
```

Then in User model, I has:

```
:id
:status(default: 0)
```

So let's say the Booking model has:

```
:id(1)
:user_id(1)
:status(0)
```

So the question is, how do I define in the **User** model if `booking.status == 1` then it will update the user status attributes from 0 to 1?

I've tries something like this:

```
def check_status
  if Booking.where(status: 2, user_id: self.id)
    self.update_attributes(:status => 1)
  end
end
```

The problem with code above is it will update ALL the user status == 1. What I want is just to update the user status if their booking (belongs_to relationship) has status == 2

Edited (1):

Booking status explanation

```
0 = Active
1 = Closed
2 = Expired
```

User status explanation

```
0 = Active
1 = Suspend
```

Comment: User has_many bookings ?

Comment: @R_O_R yes. User has many bookings and booking belongs to user

Comment: Now say User have 3 booking and one is having status 1 and rest all 2, 3 etc.. then what you want ?

Comment: Ok.. booking has status 0, 1, 2 only. Let's says the user has 3 booking and one is having status 1, another one 3 and last one 2. it still giving the user status 1.. as long as the booking has status == 2, user status will become 1

Comment: check out state machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `User` model :

```
def update_status
  self.update(status: 1) if self.bookings.pluck(:status).include? 2
end
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Humm.. Just for clarity I do use.. :) I feel good, otherwise sometime I loose my vision to understand what it is... in large codebase.. :)

Comment: It giving me an error which is ```TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer```

Comment: still got an error : ```ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)```

Comment: @AmirolAhmad fixed. no bug now anymore :)

Comment: yeay. u did it LOL. thanks alot! one more question, lets say the booking status has turn from 2 to 1. but the user status is still 1. so how do i check if that there are no more booking status == 2 for that user, then user status has change back to 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79694/discussion-between-r-o-r-and-amirolahmad).

Answer (score 1):

In the Booking model

`after_save :update_user`

```
private
 def update_user
  user.status = 1 if status = 2
end
```

EDIT: as per your CRON requirement:

```
def check_status
 self.update_attributes({status: 1}) unless bookings.where(status: 2).empty?
end
```

EDIT EDIT: Using the booking to keep track of user status:

`after_save :update_status`

```
private
def after_save
 switch(status)
 when 1
  user.update_attributes({status: 0})
 when 2
  user.update_attributes({status: 1})
end
```

Comment: Not working. Btw, I want this to be happen at User model not Booking model

Comment: when do you want it to happen in the user model? Are you going to periodically call check_status?

Comment: Yes.. the reason is I use cron to check if the booking has status == 2 and belong to user == 1 (for example), the user 1 status will automatically update to 1

Comment: updated the answer. You shouldn't call your method `check_status` if it's going to do more than check. Call it `update_status`

Comment: its work! thanks alot.. May i know one thing how should i up check the status lets say the booking status has back to 1. then automatically change back the user status to 0

Comment: You really need to use state machine. Check out AASM. It will handle all these transition changes for you in real time as opposed to running a cron job. But to answer your question, when you update the booking, you can user the after_save callback as shown in the first part of the answer above. Let me edit it for you.